# How to load related items in react using rest api hypermedia(HATEOAS)

Tags: reactjs, rest

I'm trying to build a `react` website using `Spring Data Rest Repository`. I've `User 1-1 Role` relationship.

```
// users repository response
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "users" : [ {
      "firstName" : "Adam",
      "lastName" : "Thomas",
      "email" : "adma.thomas@example.com",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/users/1"
        },
        "user" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/users/1"
        },
        "role" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/users/1/role"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/users"
    }
  }
}

// roles rest api response
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "users" : [ {
      "name" : "Admin",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/roles/1"
        },
        "user" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/roles/1"
        }
      }
    },{
      "name" : "Developer",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/roles/2"
        },
        "user" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/roles/2"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/roles"
    }
  }
}
```

On a users page, I want to show all Users with their roles.

```css
table, table tr, table th, table td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Role</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <body>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>Adam Thomas</th>
      <th>Admin</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>Alex Shaw</th>
      <th>Developoer</th>
    </tr>
  </body>
</table>
```

In react app I've loaded all users using useEffect hook and can show user names.

```
userEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/users")
        .then(response => setUsers(response.data._embedded.users))            
});
```

How can I load the related roles and populate role column for each role? Do I've to iterate on each role api endpoint and pull the role name?

**UPDATED as per @Anandhu Remanan & Ref: [Spring rest react example](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/)**

```
export default function Users() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    follow(client, API_ROOT, [{ rel: "users" }])
      .then((userCollection) => {
        return userCollection.entity._embedded.users.map(
          (user) =>
            client({
              method: "GET",
              path: user._links.self.href,
            })
        );
      })
      .then((userPromises) => {
        return when.all(userPromises);
      })
      .then((users) => {
        setUsers(users.map((user) => user.entity));

        return users.map((user) => {
          return client({
            method: "GET",
            path: user.entity._links.role.href,
          });
        });
      })
      .then((rolePromises) => {
        return when.all(rolePromises);
      })
      .then((roles) => {
        const usersWithRole = users.map((user, index) => 
        ({
          ...user,
          userRole: roles[index].entity.name,
        })
        );
        setUsers(usersWithRole);
      });
  }, []);

  const userList = users.map((user) => {
    return (
      <tr key={user._links.self.href}>
        <td className="center">{user.firstName} {user.lastName}</td>
        <td>{user.userRole}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  });

  return (
    <table>
      <caption>Users:</caption>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Role</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>{userList}</tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

Now I see nothing on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update `useEffect` as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/users")
    .then(response => {
      const users = response.data._embedded.users;

      // Create an array of promises to fetch roles for each user
      const rolePromises = users.map(user =>
        axios.get(user._links.role.href).then(response => response.data.name)
      );

      // Execute all promises and update the state with roles
      Promise.all(rolePromises)
        .then(roles => {
          const usersWithRoles = users.map((user, index) => ({
            ...user,
            role: roles[index]
          }));

          setUsers(usersWithRoles);
        });
    });
});
```

Then in your table, you can iterate over `users` to render data along with their roles as follows:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Role</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {users.map((user, index) => (
      <tr key={index}>
        <td>{index + 1}</td>
        <td>{user.firstName} {user.lastName}</td>
        <td>{user.role}</td>
      </tr>
    ))}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: updated the code as per your suggestion and [link](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/). However, I see nothing on the screen. Could you please suggest what more changes required?

Comment: Hi @KiranKyle, I've made some updates to the code. Please do check it Here [ rb.gy/35e81 ].